# Importação de XLS para PgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, tabela-html, importação, xls, pgadmin

Estou tentando importar uma planilha com as informações de uma tabela do banco de dados, porém, quando tento fazer a importação, da a seguinte mensagem:

> field 'md5' must have a value

Porém, existe valores neste campo. Não sei mais o que fazer a respeito.

Comment: Vi uma orientação sobre importar arquivo *.csv será que você consegue converter estes dados para *.csv para tentar importar? Segue o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400173/how-should-i-import-data-from-csv-into-a-postgres-table-using-pgadmin-3

Comment: Consegui thainá. obrigado. ;-)

Comment: Yey! \o/ Vou colocar como resposta, por ser uma solução possível. Sucesso aí!

Answer (score 0):

Solução paliativa: Transformar o arquivo *.xls em arquivo *.csv e importá-lo.

Você deve criar sua tabela primeiro e, em seguida, você pode importar dados com facilidade, clicando com o botão direito do mouse no nome da tabela e em seguida em "Importar".

Link com a orientação completa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400173/how-should-i-import-data-from-csv-into-a-postgres-table-using-pgadmin-3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]